# What is the reason for the link between tachanun and yehei ratzon?

Tags: tefilla

If there is no tachanun we do not say the yehei ratzons before returning the Torah to the Aron, which are usually said on Mondays and Thursdays.  So, these two parts of the service are linked in some way.  What is the reason/logic of the linkage?